# DV01 for Bond Forwards

Tags: bond, forward, dv01

Does anyone know how to get the DV01 of bond forwards from Bloomberg? I used FPA to get the forward price but can't figure out how to get the DV01.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried F1 F1?

Comment: @Stepanie  Can you get the duration of the bond forward?